# Java Server & SSL Socket Setup - Will this code work?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, server

I am coding a web server in Java and so far everything is working nicely. However, since I am unable to obtain a SSL Certificate to test with, I do not have a way to test my server over https. Except for the following code, my server is written to respond to https requests the same way as it does with http requests. Would it work?

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStorePath);//The path to the trust store file
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);//The trust store password
    try(SSLServerSocket socket = (SSLServerSocket) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(ssl_listen_port)) {
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        System.out.println("\tServer SSL socket created on port " + ssl_listen_port);
        while(serverActive) {
            //Omitted multithreading code for read-ability:
            final SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) socket.accept();
            try {
                s.startHandshake();
            } catch(SSLHandshakeException e) {
                System.err.println("Failed to initialize SSL handshake: " + e.getMessage());
                continue;               
            }

            //(The server then handles the remainder of the request as if it were http.)
        }
    } catch(BindException e) {
        System.err.println(" /!\\\tUnable to bind to ssl port " + ssl_listen_port + ":\r\n/___\\\t" + e.getMessage());
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I apologize in advance if this sort of question has already been asked or if I have done something wrong.

Comment: You can create your own certificate: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjrgy/index.html

Comment: Now, if it is a keystore, would that mean that I need to use "javax.net.ssl.keystore" instead of truststore?

Comment: So I used the keyStore system property and then opened https://localhost in google chrome, but it said that the certificate is not trusted, so I told it to connect anyway and then I eventually get a 408 response from my server. Any clue why it timed out?

Comment: Calling `socket.setReuseAddress(true);` *after* specifying the port is pointless.

Comment: Ah, okay, but that does not appear to have caused the timeouts because the 408 response that shows up in chrome is the one generated from my server. Something is causing both the client and the server to wait on each other(chrome says "waiting for localhost..." and the server is waiting on the client to send its request... Strange.

Comment: I fiigured it out! Apparently waiting for the inputstream to have bytes available works for normal http connections, but with https connections it always just blocks, so I had to add an exception for https connections. Weird.

Comment: I didn't claim that not calling `setReuseAddress()` would fix your problem. I merely commented that it was pointless. You don't need to call `startHandshake()` either. It is automatic on the first I/O. And you certainly shouldn't do it in the accept loop. And you should close the socket if the handshake failed. Lots of things wrong here,

Comment: I omitted the sections of the code for read-ability; I do perform cleanup operations such as closing the sockets etc. Thanks for pointing those things out though.